# Underlining text in vi

Tags: text-files, markdown, vi

Is there a quick way to insert a line with the same number of hyphens or `=` characters as there are in the current line in vi(m)? That is, to go from:

```
My Heading
```

to:

```
My Heading
==========
```

without going to the end of the line, reading the number of characters in it from CTRL-G, opening a new line underneath, and typing `<n>i=` ?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following mappings in my own `markdown.vim`:

```
" Level 1 Heading
nnoremap <leader>1 :co.<CR>Vr=A<CR><Esc>
inoremap <leader>1 <Esc>:co.<CR>Vr=A<CR>
```

The first mapping is for when already in Normal mode while the second Insert mode mapping returns to Insert mode with the cursor at the start of the line underneath the heading.

1. Use the Ex copy command, `:co` to copy the line without affecting the contents of any of the Vim registers.
2. Then select all of the copied line with `V`.
3. Finally, `r=` replaces each of those characters with an equal sign.

For the mapping keys, I use the leader key (defaults to `\`) followed by the numeral `1` to represent a Level 1 heading in Markdown.